# Hide grid Panel Column programmatically ExtJs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect

I want to hide a column in grid panel of ExtJs 5 when store associated with grid panel loads .

Comment: But how to get access to a grid panel column and hide it

Comment: grid reconfigure. Thats what I would use. have a look at this for example. http://jsfiddle.net/prajavk/t2bvj/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your data store works.... there is onload event. Hide your column on that event.

Comment: I want to know how we need to code in extjs to  access and hide column

Answer (score 0):

Using the following syntax you can achieve it:

```
   <yourGrid>.down('headercontainer').getGridColumns()[<columnIndex>].hidden = true;
```

Comment: Should I keep the name 'headercontainer' as it is

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the column to hide you can use this code after store load event fired

```
grid.getColumnManager().getHeaderAtIndex(indexOfColumn).hide()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the api from manual [Ext.grid.column.Column-method-hide]: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-hide

There is a fiddle for you: http://runjs.cn/code/qusp7pql